# TYPO3 gridelements not selectable

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-gridelements

I'm running a TYPO3 webseite with TYPO3 version 7.6.16 and the extensions gridelements 7.0.5. In backend the selection for gridelements is empty ... what could be the reason?

[image]

also missing is this tap in new page item wizard

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the steps in manual?
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/gridelements/Chapters/Installation/Index.html

- Include static template
- Create some CE backend layouts
- Create new Grid Elements

Comment: Please help others and post your solution.